# Linux server - configured as router

Tags: linux, networking, ip, router

I'm following [the below link](http://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administrations/linux-as-router.html) to configure Linux server as Router.

I would like to know if the Linux server will behave as actual router i.e. Suppose if it receives a packet whose MTU size is greater than next hop, it will drop the packet ?

Answer (score 1):

The server will not necessarily drop the packet. It will fragment it, unless the Don't Fragment bit is set. In this case it will respond with a Destination Unreachable ICMP message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case of IPv6, it needs to drop the packet right, and also if the Don't fragment is set, then we can expect ICMP - Packet Too Big message